# AngularJS broadcast returns undefined

Tags: angularjs, broadcast

I make a get request like this :

```
ChartFactory.get({id: $scope.selectedItem}, function(data) {
    $scope.selectedItem = data;
    console.log($scope.selectedVal);


    $rootScope.$broadcast('selectedParams',function(event, selectedVal){});
});
```

I want to broadcast what returns my get request to the main controller and I do something like this:

```
$rootScope.$on('selectedParams', function() {

    console.log("!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
    console.log($rootScope.selectedVal);
})
```

but it returns undefined. Am I missing something. Did I not broadcast the message correctly?

After i broadcast my message i want to use my selectedVal in another controller. I tried like this:

```
    $scope.$watch('selectedParams', function(){
                console.log($scope.selectedParams);
                console.log("ChangedParams");
                ChartData();
            },true);
```

Is this ok. Am i using th $watch function correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

$rootScope.$broadcast('selectedParams', {data: $scope.selectedVal});

First parameter is event name.
Second is data that this event brings.

> Blockquote $broadcast(name, args);
>   Dispatches an event name downwards to all child scopes (and their children) notifying the registered $rootScope.Scope listeners.

Answer (score 0):

Broadcast like this:

```
$rootScope.$broadcast('selectedParams', { selectedParams: $scope.selectedVal });
```

And then receive it:

```
$scope.$on('selectedParams', function(event, args) {

    var mySelectedParam = args.selectedParams;
    // do what you want to do
});
```